# VertrigoServ is not starting

Tags: mysql, apache, windows-8

When I try to start my VertrigoServ in a tray, suddenly it appears a window over there, saying that:

**Apache HTTP server and MySQL database server do not work correctly. Check whether other applications use the important ports (80 and 3306) and terminate them. Moreover, check firewall settings and correctness the configuration files.**

Well, to begin with, I'm using Windows 8. 
I've already opened: 
**C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\Apache\httpd.conf** file to correct the port number from 8080 to 80 (as it was suggested in one youtube tutorial, that to prevent stopping it to run. However there was no need to fix that, as it was already written necessary **Listen 80**  (port 80) in that file.

**To Be honest, I tried to retype **Listen 80** to **85** just for testing purposes, however I cannot save that update in a file, as it's asking me to save **the file somewhere outside the Vertrigoserv folder**. However there's no option like **"Run as Administraor"** in a drop down menu, when you open this file (**httpd.conf**). Can anybody suggest anything sufficient over this ?

Secondly, also tried to find out if **3306 port** is being used, so typed **netstat** in **cmd** 
and the list of used ports showed that I have only 66 ports being used.

So, I realise we can try to fix something in **Windows Firewall**, however I don't really know what..I didn't touch it yes, as still haven't find any sufficient information.

**Please help!**

Comment: Your machine will already be listening on port 80 for internet traffic. If you are using it for dev just leave it at 8080. (also, save the file elsewhere then copy it in when you get that message, that is what I do at least.)

Comment: well, yeah it's listening to 80 port. but it's not solving out  an issue...

Comment: Stop it listening to 80 then. This is actually the wrong place to ask this question anyway. Try http://serverfault.com/